# How to write $\min\{a,k\}+\min\{b,k\}$ as one min?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, combinatorics, notation, maxima-minima

I want to simplify a solution to a problem I have where I used to write
$$\min\{a,k\} + \min\{b,k\} \leq \min\{c,k\} + \min\{d,k\}.$$
I am wondering: is there a more simplified way of writing this line since $k$ is a common argument in all minimums?

Comment: $\min\{a+b,2k,k+a,k+b\}$?

Comment: Your title is 'write this as one min' ; your question is 'write this in a more simplified way'. At the end, it seems that writing this as one min is really NOT a more simplified way.

Comment: You recieved 2 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider accepting the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Comment: @5xum Sure I will do that .... I just have to read them thoroughly first.

Comment: @Secretly You sure take a long time to read through two questions...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your expression will always equal $$\min\{a+b, a+k, k+b, 2k\}.$$ However, whether that is simpler than your expression is subjective. I would say the original is clearer.

Answer (score 0):

If we don’t know which is smaller than other, we may use analytic approximation:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{\log(e^{ax} + e^{bx})}{x} = \min\{a,b\}$$

Now, in our case;

\begin{align}
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{\log(e^{ax} + e^{kx})}{x} + \lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{\log(e^{bx} + e^{kx})}{x} \\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{\log((e^{ax} + e^{kx})(e^{bx} + e^{kx}))}{x} \\
&=\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{\log(e^{(a+b)x} + e^{(a+k)x}+ e^{(b+k)x}+ e^{(2k)x})}{x} \\
&=\min\{a+b, a+k, b+k, 2k\}
\end{align}

This was already a result shown by @5xum. I was just explaining how this happened.

Comment: Easier explanation is: let $~S = \{a,k\}, T = \{b,k\}.~$ Then, $~\min(a,k) + \min(b,k)~$ must equal $~(s + t) ~: ~s \in S, ~t \in T.~$  Then, you simply mention that $~S \times T~$ has $~4~$ elements, because $~S~$ and $~T~$ each have two elements.  So, there are $~4~$ possible values of $~(s+t),~$ and per the constraints, you want the smallest of the $~4~$ values.

Comment: This is a total overcomplication. First of all, we can WLOG assume $a\leq b$. Then we have only three cases to analyze: $k\leq a\leq b$, $a\leq k\leq b$ and $a\leq b\leq k$. In all three cases, you get the equality OP needs.

Comment: why $$\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{log(e^{ax} + e^{bx})}{x} = min\{a,b\}?$$

Comment: @Leox Actually it comes from $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty } \frac{log(e^{ax}+e^{bx})}{x} = max\{a,b\}$. When x tends to infinity, one of $e^{ax}$ or $e^{bx}$ will remain small enough to be ignored compared to the other. Thus we have $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} \frac{log(e^{ax})}{x} = a$. (We assume a is bigger than b). If you want to convert the max function to min function, use $min\{a,b\}=-max\{-a,-b\}$.

Comment: No, $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} \frac{log(e^{ax} + e^{bx})}{x} = a+b.$

Comment: @Leox https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=limit+of+log%28e%5E%283x%29+%2B+e%5E%285x%29%29%2Fx+as+x+to+infinity

Comment: @5xum   Maple  gives $a+b$

Comment: @Leox Well then either maple or the way you wrote your input is wrong...

Comment: yes, it seems Maple is wrong